# Can a logarithm to a power be hand-written in the same way as trigonometry?

Tags: notation, logarithms

I know that $(\sin(x))^n$ can be hand-written as $\sin^n(x)$, along with other trigonometry.

Is this the same for logarithms? i.e. can I write $(\ln(x))^n$ as $\ln^n(x)$?

Comment: Sure it can ........

Comment: If you explain what you mean you can get away with (almost) any notation.

Comment: Ok, thanks guys!

Comment: For what its worth, iterated (composition) logarithms are common in mathematics (but not iterated trig functions), and they are sometimes written [with a subscript](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NestedLogarithm.html), but of course this notation conflicts with usual base-of-logarithm notation (but it's usually only used in advanced settings where $\log$ denotes the natural logarithm). I think I've sometimes seen a superscripted logarithm denote an iterated logarithm, but I don't know any references for this now. Note, however, the [explicitness here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/408601/15780).